# Logfiles ending with ".1"

Tags: linux, file, logging

Why my logsfiles ending with ".1" ?
Its just a new file for log ?

```sh
-rw-r----- 1 root adm         0 Mar 14 10:56 auth.log
-rw-r----- 1 root adm   8998827 Mar 14 00:00 auth.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 root adm      5241 Mar 14 10:55 daemon.log
-rw-r----- 1 root adm     97769 Mar 14 00:00 daemon.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 root adm         0 Mar 14 00:00 debug
-rw-r----- 1 root adm     16853 Mar 11 20:51 debug.1
-rw-r----- 1 root adm         0 Mar 14 00:00 kern.log
-rw-r----- 1 root adm     87015 Mar 11 20:51 kern.log.1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root utmp   292292 Mar 14 10:39 lastlog
-rw-r----- 1 root adm       154 Mar 14 00:00 messages
-rw-r----- 1 root adm     73418 Mar 14 00:00 messages.1
-rw-r----- 1 root adm         0 Mar 14 00:00 user.log
-rw-r----- 1 root adm      2168 Mar 11 20:51 user.log.1
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) in action. That's [how it works](https://www.networkworld.com/article/3218728/how-log-rotation-works-with-logrotate.html):

> Log rotation is the process that renames a current log file (e.g.,
> auth.log becomes auth.log.1) and sets up a new log file (e.g.,
> auth.log) for new log entries.
>
> Rotating log files is important for several reasons. First, you
> probably don't want older log files eating up too much of your disk
> space. Second, when you need to analyze log data, you probably don't
> want those log files to be extremely large and cumbersome. And last,
> organizing log files by date probably makes spotting and analyzing
> changes quite a bit easier (e.g., comparing last week's log data to
> this week's).

You didn't mention the OS in question: [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manage-logfiles-with-logrotate-on-ubuntu-16-04), for example, described how one can set up and configure `logrotate` on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, and for the OS its Debian